# VLOOKUP Error "did not find value" but value is defenitely there?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to match the postcode with the name of the city in another sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(C11,PLZ_2021_DE!A:B,2)
```

[Here's the sheet I want the place in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fich2.png)

[And here the sheet I want to match it with, just column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fnEa.png)

[Here's the link to the file, I don't get what I'm doing wrong?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ddwg4QQgAwjDOpdWuasLUdZoOffHtzrCdlh3gFe_f4E/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If one sheet has the value stored as text and the other has the value stored as a number it will never match.  Do you know the format the values are stored in?  It looks like the PLZ column is text because it has a leading zero.  What about C11 ?  If that is the problem you could `=VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(C11),PLZ_2021_DE!A:B,2)`

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually thought both has to be stored/formatted as text? I used "number" and then "Plain text". So either both need to be saved as number or as text, right? So the solution was you adding "to_text" right? Becuase once postcode was apparently text the other a number right?

Answer (score 0):

delete E2:E rnge and use this in E2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C&"", TO_TEXT(PLZ_2021_DE!A:B), 2, 0)
```

`0` coz you want exact matches and `&""`/`TO_TEXT` coz C column has probably different formatting than A column assuming due to different cell alignment

[image]